# How to upload and retrieve pdf file in sqllite database

Tags: android-listview, textview, android-edittext, android-sqlite, pdf-generation

I want upload pdf file into sqlite and retrieve the pdf file into listview how can I do that please send me the code after I retrieve the pdf file in list view it as to open in pdf file how can I do that please help me out

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

I personally suggest you to use the cloud firestore to your application which will be helpful to upload or access the contents of files.

you can save the files in the firebase storage and then use the links to access them and list into the listview

Comment: is possible to save file in sqlite

Comment: Upto my knowledge if you want to store some data you have to keep them in the storage server and can retrieve them. If you want to use sqlite database then I suggest you to use 000webhost.